# python lxml attribute namespaces within namespaces

Tags: python, lxml, xml-namespaces

In the documentation I'm looking at for a file upload, it needs this specific tag at the beginning of the xml file:

```
<oclcPersonas xmlns="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/IDMPersonas-2.2" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/IDMPersonas-2.2 IDMPersonas-2.2.xsd">
```

I'm trying to use the lxml.etree library to figure this out.

Many of the examples I've seen have a initial level of namespace for attributes that would cover the `xmlns:xsi` portion using this:

```
namespace_map = {
        None: persona_namespace,
        'xsi': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}
```

but 2 questions arise from the second portion `xsi:schemaLocation`

1) How would I accomplish a secondary level of namespace using lxml?

2) How do I allow the namespaces to contain a space without receiving an error (`http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/IDMPersonas-2.2 IDMPersonas-2.2.xsd`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample XML, you have :

- a root element `oclcPersonas` in the default namespace,
- a default namespace: "http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/IDMPersonas-2.2",
- a “xsi” namespace: "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
- a “schemaLocation” attribute in the “xsi” namespace.

To build this element with lxml, you need to use the fully-qualified name using curly braces (James Clark notation).

First define a dictionary which store your namespace mapping:

```
# your namespaces
p_url = "http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/IDMPersonas-2.2"
xsi_url = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
NS = {None: p_url, 'xsi': xsi_url}
```

In order to build fully-qualified namespace, you can define prefixes:

```
# tag prefixes
P = '{' + p_url + '}'
XSI = '{' + xsi_url + '}'
```

Then you can define the tag names and attributes:

```
# tag names and attributes
root_tag = P + 'oclcPersonas'
attrs = {
    XSI + 'schemaLocation':
    "http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/IDMPersonas-2.2 IDMPersonas-2.2.xsd"
}
```

The root element can be created like below:

```
# element
root = etree.Element(root_tag, attrib=attrs, nsmap=NS)
```

You should have your element:

```
print(etree.tounicode(root))
```

To answer your question:

> 2) How do I allow the namespaces to contain a space without receiving an error (`http://worldcat.org/xmlschemas/IDMPersonas-2.2 IDMPersonas-2.2.xsd`)

This is not a namespace, this is the value of the `schemaLocation` attribute. A simple string.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked Perfectly